# Ordering int pairs

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list of int pairs such as:

```
 [(1,2),(3,5),(0,1),(1,3),(3,0),(0,3)]
```

I want to order this list from the smallest pair to the greatest. For the example above, it should be:

```
 [(0,1),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(3,0),(3,5)].
```

You can assume that there will be no same pair in the list in the given input.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the function `sort` from `Data.List`. It works on any type which is an instance of `Ord` and pairs are indeed instances.

Answer (score 3):

Tuples of 2 `Ord` values (including `Int`s) are instances of `Ord` class in turn, so you can just [`sort`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3asort) the list.